# How to get the primary key based on the users email? PHP& MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, primary-key

This is the code when the user logs in:

```
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Email']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['Password']);

  if (empty($email)) {
    array_push($errors, "email is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM organisers WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: loggedInInterface/loggedIN.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong email/password combination");
    }
  }
}
```

Don't worry, I'll clean up my code later.
As you can see, they are going to log in using their email and password. How do I get the users primary key value?

Note: primary key column name = 'organiserID'

Comment: what is the userprimary key value? only u know that

Comment: What is the main key called? It looks like it would be stored in `$results` when you're done.

Comment: You really should not store plain-text passwords.

Comment: A must read for you for handling passwords http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php and to prevent SQL injections https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137741/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-php

Comment: ^... Nor an MD5 hash of it, use the native `password_*` PHP functions

Comment: I know the primary key value when I log into phpmyadmin and check the table. But I need that primary key value???

Comment: i don't understand in what way your problem is "email" related... you seem to have other issues (hashing, prepared statements, accessing data, fetching records, but no 'email problem' as your post title say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
$primaryKey = $row[organiserID];

For some reason you have to use "mysqli_fetch_assoc" instead of using "mysqli_fetch_row".

Answer (score 0):

Include this after your 'if' statement and you can then access it:

```
$primaryKey = $row['nameOfPrimaryKeyColumn'];
```

Comment: What is `nameOfPrimaryKeyColumn`?

Comment: Whatever the name of the primary key column in your table in your database is called.

Comment: which if statement??

Comment: if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {

Comment: How do I check if it works?? I tried to echo it but there's no value showing up.

Comment: Are you able to show me all your code and also the database table please. Will make things a lot clearer!

Answer (score 0):

$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[organiserID];

Comment: I tried that, but how come I'm getting no values printed. I understand that $row is an array. And if you do $row[columnName], it should return the column value but I'm getting nothing. I feel like I'm doing a silly mistake or i'm missing something

Comment: if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $row=mysqli_fetch_row($results);
      echo $row[organiserID];

Comment: actually i was given just exaple you should write $row=mysqli_fetch_row($results); Results for that try this